# All non-isomorphic transitive actions of the Dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Consider the Dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2n$ as a permutation group. That is $$D_n = \langle (1,2,\ldots, n), (1)(2, n-1)(3,n-2) \cdots \rangle.$$

I would like to determine all faithful transitive actions of $D_n$ up to isomorphism/equivalence the later notion being defined in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142760/isomorphic-but-not-equivalent-actions-of-a-group-g)  post and also appearing on  [this](https://books.google.si/books?id=4QDpFN6k61EC&lpg=PP1&dq=permutation%20groups&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=permutation%20groups&f=false) page of the book about Permutation groups.

For convenience - we say that two group actions $\alpha,\beta : G \mapsto S_n$ are *isomorphic* if there is an automorphism $f:G \mapsto G$ and bijection $\varphi:[n] \mapsto [n]$ such that

$$\varphi(o^{\alpha(g)}) = \varphi(o)^{\beta(f(g))} \quad \mbox{ for all } o \in [n], g \in G.$$

If $f$ can be chosen as the identity map then we say that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are *equivalent*.

From the theory in the linked book I know that the problem of determining all non-equivalent transitive group actions it is enough to find all subgroups of $D_n$ up to conjugacy.

What I am struggling with is,

> how to obtain all faithful and transitive group actions of $D_n$ up to isomorphism?

Comment: Have you tried yet to enumerate all subgroups of $D_n$?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, but I don't know how this gives me all actions of $D_n$ modulo isomorphism

Comment: You mean that you do not understand the proof of the theorem from the book?

Comment: @LeeMosher Which theorem exactly? I only covered Lemma1.6B which allows one to find transitive actions up to equivalence.

Comment: You want the subgroups up to equivalence under ${\rm Aut}(G)$. When $n$ is odd, this is the same as equvialence under ${\rm Inn}(G)$, so the transitive perm reps are equivalent if and only if they are isomorphic. When $n$ is even,  you get two classes of subgroups $D_m$ when $n/m$ is even (including $m=1$), and they are equivalent uner ${\rm Aut}(G)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you please elaborate a bit more about this? I spent a day on it but don't see an easy way to deduce that for $n$ odd we only need consider subgroups up to conjugacy and the structure of the isomorphism classes under $\rm{Aut}(G)$. Thanks